# How to start for-each loop from the beginning?

Tags: android, foreach

I'm writing the For-each loop and inside the for-each loop I,m checking a condition. I want to restart the loop if that condition is met. Is there any keyword like **continue** or **break** for start the loop from the beginning

```
 for (PoDetails items : ordersItemList) {
    if (nextPosition == incrementPosition) {
        if (some condition){
            break;
        } else{
            if (some condition){
                continue;
            } else{
                //I want to restart the for-each loop here
            }
         }
    } else {
        nextPosition++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Through recursion you can achieve that,
put this code in separate function, call that function where you want to start it again

Comment: There is a simple workaround instead of restarting the for loop just create a method with your for loop inside it and just initialize that method inside your for loop when that condition is met!

Comment: you could put the for each loop inside a do while loop

Comment: Try using my solution. It will help you

Comment: just put your for loop in a method and call it from inside that loop. Method Recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an index in the for loop, Then when you need to restart the loop set this index to zero.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ordersItemList.size(); i++) {
    PoDetails item = ordersItemList.get(i);
    if (nextPosition == incrementPosition) {
        if (some condition) {
            break;
        } else {
            if (some condition) {
                continue;
            }else{
                //I want to restart the for-each loop here
                i = 0; // set the index to zero here, then it will start the loop from the begnning
            }
        }
    } else {
        nextPosition++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OUTER: //outer label
for (PoDetails items : ordersItemList) {
    if (nextPosition == incrementPosition) {
        if (some condition){
            break;
        } else{
            if (some condition){
                continue;
            } else{
                continue OUTER:; // This will call the loop from OUTER:
            }
        }
    } else {
        nextPosition++;
    }
}
```